# Rotating Empty Sphere around stationary black hole

Tags: black-holes

Would it be possible to create a habitable in terms of gravity planet that would rotate with the black hole acting as a center of gravity? The rotation of the structure would lessen the gravitational force, so it would be much harder to access it from outside. Would the rotation of the planet be sufficient to lessen the pull of the black hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a [Dyson sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere), there should be no difference, in terms of gravitational forces, if the central object is a star or a black hole (of the same mass).

See also [Niven Ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven_ring) - where rotation is used to provide artificial gravity.